# Download a text file without displaying save file popup in an electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, anchor

In my electron app, I am taking user input in a text field and trying to download that text as a csv file on button click. The below JS function is working fine but it displays a popup along with the file name and ask to click save button before starting download. How can I get rid of the popup and download it automatically?

```
// Function to download CSV file
function downloadCSV(filename, text) {
  const element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename + '.csv');

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);

   // Display file location in console
  const fileLocation = `Saved file: ${filename}.csv`;
  console.log(fileLocation);
}
```

Comment: Browsers won't download files without the user authorizing it.

Comment: @Barmar I am running the app as a desktop application. Is it not even allowed in standalone electron app?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not familiar with Electron, and I don't know whether libchromium enforces browser security like when it's used to implement a full browser.